# Adding Discussion Board Links within New Tasks.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

What I would like to do is when I add a task I want to be able to click a button within the task and  create a discussion board item  with the same title as shown in the following screenshot.  I would like for me to be able to go straight to the discussion like I have it linked now and in the discussion to link back to the task.

I did this all manually for each task, but it would be great if I can do it for all Tasks when I am creating the task.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sahil,

We did this once in SP2007,  assuming that you are doing this using SharePoint object model and custom code,  i would suggest that create an event handler that creates a disucssion with the task title.

Remember that Discussion list has two content types,  one if of Folder Content type and another is Item.  So when we create a new discussion it actually creates a folder with title and all the conversation is stored within the folder.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. I am doing this in SP2010, I am a novice to SharePoint, don't exactly know how to create event handlers. I will work on it.